# Evaluate sum using generating function

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions, binomial-theorem

I'm trying to evaluate this sum:

$$ \sum\limits_{s = 0}^{500} (-1)^s \binom{3000 - 2s}{2000} \binom{2001}{s}$$

As I think we need to use an expansion of $(1 -x)^n (1+x)^k$, but I've tried several times, using different powers but stuck every time.

Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**  Please note, this is essentially the same as Marko Riedels answer. Here we simply avoid  the integral notation which might be somewhat more convenient.

> In order to calculate OPs sum it's beneficial to consider the more general expression
>
> \begin{align*}
> S_n=\sum_{s= 0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}(-1)^s\binom{3n-2s}{2n}\binom{2n+1}{s}
> \end{align*}

We obtain OPs expression by setting $n=1000$. We need one additional small step before we start calculating $S_n$.

Since $\binom{m}{k}=\binom{m}{m-k}$ and $\binom{-m}{k}=\binom{m+k-1}{k}(-1)^k$ the following is valid
\begin{align*}
\binom{3n-2s}{2n}=\binom{3n-2s}{n-2s}=\binom{-(2n+1)}{n-2s}(-1)^n
\end{align*}

> So, we can rewrite $S_n$ as
>   \begin{align*}
> S_n=(-1)^n\sum_{s= 0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}(-1)^s\binom{-(2n+1)}{n-2s}\binom{2n+1}{s}
> \end{align*}

Observe the nice  symmetry regarding $2n+1$. This will help simplifying $S_n$.

> In the following we use the  *[coefficient of](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9402216)* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ of a polynomial or a series.
>
> We obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> S_n&=(-1)^n\sum_{s= 0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}(-1)^s\binom{-(2n+1)}{n-2s}\binom{2n+1}{s}\\
> &=(-1)^n\sum_{s= 0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}[x^{n-2s}](1+x)^{-(2n+1)}[y^s](1-y)^{2n+1}\tag{1}\\
> &=(-1)^n[x^n](1+x)^{-(2n+1)}\sum_{s= 0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}x^{2s}[y^s](1-y)^{2n+1}\tag{2}\\
> &=(-1)^n[x^n](1+x)^{-(2n+1)}(1-x^2)^{2n+1}\tag{3}\\
> &=(-1)^n[x^n](1-x)^{2n+1}\tag{4}\\
> &=\binom{2n+1}{n}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we write the binomial coefficients as coefficients of polynomials (resp. series) $\binom{m}{k}=[x^k](1+x)^m$. Note, that the factor $(-1)^s$ is respected in  $[y^s](1-y)^{2n+1}$.
- In (2) we see that the representation as coefficients of polynomials is convenient, since we can put parts of the expression, which do not depend on $s$ outside the sum. We also use the rule $$[x^{n+m}]p(x)=[x^n]x^{-m}p(x)$$
- In (3) we use the substitution rule (see also (1)):
  \begin{align*}
  (1-x^2)^{2n+1}&=\sum_{s\geq 0}\binom{2n+1}{s}(-1)^sx^{2s}\\
  &=\sum_{s\geq 0}x^{2s}[y^s](1-y)^{2n+1}
  \end{align*}
- In (4) we use the symmetry regarding $2n+1$ which helps cancelling a factor of $(1-x^2)^{2n+1}=(1-x)^{2n+1}(1+x)^{2n+1}$

> Since OPs expression is $S_{1000}$ we finally conclude
>   \begin{align*}
> S_{1000}&=\sum_{s=0}^{500}(-1)^s\binom{3000-2s}{2000}\binom{2001}{s}\\
> &=[x^{1000}](1+x)^{2001}\\
> &=\binom{2001}{1000}
> \end{align*}

Comment: @Acapello: You're welcome! :-)

Comment: Oh, wait. It seems like I miss one moment: sum is from 0 to 500. But bound 3n - 2s < 0 means that all members with s < 1500 counted in yours solution. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Acappello: You're right, thanks! Indexing was not correct. I've changed it by respecting the strict upper limit $\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we seek to evaluate
$$S_n = 
\sum_{q=0}^n (-1)^q {6n-2q\choose 4n} {4n+1\choose q}.$$

Introduce 
$${6n-2q\choose 4n} = 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{w^{2n-2q+1}} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{4n+1}} \; dw.$$

This is zero when $q\gt n$  so we may extend the summation to infinity
to obtain
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{w^{2n+1}} \frac{1}{(1-w)^{4n+1}}
\sum_{q\ge 0} (-1)^q {4n+1\choose q} w^{2q} \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{w^{2n+1}} \frac{1}{(1-w)^{4n+1}}
(1-w^2)^{4n+1}\; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{w^{2n+1}} 
(1+w)^{4n+1}\; dw.$$

This evaluates to 
$${4n+1\choose 2n}$$ by inspection.

The desired value is given by $S_{500}.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is not what I need, but I have learned something new from your solution(integral represantation and how we can use it =)